# How to perform a "NOT IN" query in mongodb without using $nin?

Tags: mongodb

I need an **alternative to $nin** in mongodb. As we know, we can achieve the **"IN" query** operation by performing **"OR" query** as well.

In the same way, how can I achieve **"NOT IN"** functionality in mongodb without using **$nin** ? What are the **alternatives to using $nin** in mongodb to acheive exactly same results ?

Comment: Please tell about your usecase first, that way we can help you better.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: Not really that easy since whatever you do you either need to switch it for a inclusion or use a negation. If you have no choice but a $nin then that's your option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that there is a operator **$nor** which exactly does this function. It works as the **negation of $or**.

Comment: Could you please share how to have list of values to be excluded with $nor operator ? db.getCollection("test").find({"$nor": [{_id: [ObjectId("xxxxx"), ObjectId("xxxxx") .....]}]} is only excluding the first matching document

Answer (score 1):

Well, interesting, But I think It can be achieved by $not

say you have $nin for A,B and C where A,B, C are values which you want to ignore

so instead of calling **$nin : [ABC]**

what if we call **$not : {$or : [A,B,C]}**

Update :

Since $not is not working with $or. Maybe you can try [$nor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nor/) which I *hope* is basically same concept.

Comment: I tried using this way, but it said that $or is not recognized. May be $not and $or do not work together.

Comment: Yes, I found about $nor and posted my own answer just before you updated your original answer. Anyways, thank you :)