# MongoDB: Efficient $nin operator

Tags: mongodb, performance

I have two collections, they both have one common field:

**collection1**

```
{
    "myCommonFieldId" : 1
}

{ 
    "myCommonFieldId" : 2
}

{
    "myCommonFieldId" : 3
}

{
    "myCommonFieldId" : 4
}

{
    "myCommonFieldId" : 5
}
```

**collection2**

```
{
    "myCommonFieldId" : 2
}

{
    "myCommonFieldId" : 5
}
```

I want to get documents from **collection1** `which are not in` **collections2** (The uncommon `myCommonFieldId`-s between two collections). In this case:

```
{
    "myCommonFieldId" : 1
}

{
    "myCommonFieldId" : 3
}

{
    "myCommonFieldId" : 4
}
```

The straightforward solution is to query **collection2**, take the results and run ***$nin*** in **collection1**

```
db.collection2.find({}); 
db.collection1.find({"myCommonFieldId" : {$nin : [<Result from query1>]}})
```

I have a huge dataset and since ***$nin*** operator is not efficient, $nin is becoming very expensive operation for me: Quoting from MongoDB documentations:

> The inequality operator $nin is not very selective since it often matches a large portion of the index. As a result, in many cases, a $nin query with an index may perform no better than a $nin query that must scan all documents in a collection.

Is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41436937/how-to-perform-a-not-in-query-in-mongodb-without-using-nin
It suggests **$nor** as an alternative of **$nin**

Comment: Is creating a third collection to track 'membership' of the other two an option? 
`{Id : 2, Membership : [1, 2]}` or adding this information as a bool to the documents in collection 1 and updating as you add and remove collection 2 documents?

Comment: @IanMercer, can you please clarify your answer a little? How will membership help increasing performance? 
I can't actually touch the original transactions, but I can create a separate collection collection.

Comment: did you find a solution to this by any chance? I know it's been a while but I'm desparate.